# Android webview inside viewpager remains blank after a while

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview

We have an app where where we can slide using a view pager displaying fragments. Each fragment contains a webview. After sliding between a few pages, the webview remains blank even though there is content to display. A complete kill of the app gets things back in order and then the problem reappears again. We have tried a lot of different stuff without luck. Any clue would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

Could be javascript stuck in a `while(true) {}` loop. Have you tried disabling JavaScript? Does that help?